# How to disable Hyperlinks in a certain condition in RDLC

Tags: hyperlink, report, rdlc

We have an RDLC that is used in a report viewer as our main report, and another one as a subreport.

We have set a hyperlink to the cells of the first column that is used to call the subreport (By double clicking on the cell , choosing "Go to report" radio button, and specifying the subreport RDLC).

In some conditions, the cells of the first column should have this hyperlink and in some conditions they shouldn't.

How can we set this with code or expressions?

for example we need to say that if "Type == sth" go to subreport and if "Type == sth else"
don't show the hyperlink at all

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an expression in `Action` property so you can put two overlapped `TextBoxes` in your `Cell` using a `Rectangle` as a container.

One `TextBox` contains the hyperlink, the other not: using `Hidden` properties you can choose which is the one to display.